# Flask after calling logging.getLogger(__name__) logger.handlers are missing

Tags: python, logging, flask, python-logging

I am not using the built-in flask logging mechanism. Instead of that, I have created the following which was getting created from the main in flask app.

```
def init_logger(app):
    log_file = LOG_FILE

    if app.testing:
        log_file = TEST_LOG_FILE

    create_logging_folder(app)

    logger = logging.getLogger("main")

    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    rotating_file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(
        filename=log_file,
        maxBytes=10240,
        backupCount=10
    )

    rotating_file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    rotating_file_handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
        )
    )
    rotating_file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.addHandler(rotating_file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    logger.info("Test")
    logger.info(id(logger))


def create_logging_folder(app):
    log_dir = LOG_DIR

    if app.testing:
        log_dir = TEST_LOG_DIR

    if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
        os.mkdir(log_dir)

    return True
```

info and the logging id is getting created in the log file, but if I call the logger from another module I found that the handlers were empty and logs are not getting created.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.handlers) # []
```

Entry point as follows

def run():

```
 app = main.create_app()

 init_logger(app)

 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 print(logger.handlers) # stil empty

 app.run(
     debug=os.environ.get("APP_DEBUG", True),
     host=os.environ.get("APP_HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
     port=os.environ.get("APP_PORT", 5000),
 )
```

What could possibly go wrong here? How can I make this work ?

Comment: Did you put ` logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` into your entrance file, which your `main` function live in?

Comment: @FrankAK Updated and it results no handlers

Comment: You have been configuring only one logger. If you want to apply the configuration globally configure the root logger with `basicConfig()` or by using no argument to `getLogger()`.

Comment: @KlausD. it worked. though there are no handlers yet ?